# Images are not being scanned in Kitkat

Tags: gallery, images, media-scanner

I have nexus4 with Kitkat 4.4.2. I added .nomedia file in DCIM/Camera folder. After restarting the phone, Gallery didn't show any of the pics from that folder. I removed the .nomedia file from the folder, but the gallery doesn't show any images. After rebooting the phone couple of times and trying few media scanning apps, it shows new images which I took from the camera. But it doesn't show any old images.

What could be the problem? What can I do so that it shows old images too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many media scanner apps do not work as expected on KitKat. After trying couple of such apps i found that the media scan function in FX file explorer app works 100% every time you use it. It successfully updates your gallery with the changes.

Get FX file explorer from here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx

Open this app, go to 'Main Storage' & run 'Rescan Media' from menu.

Tested on Nexus 5,
Android 4.4.2